# Обложка для страницы продукта в facebook

Tags: photoshop

Делаю страницу продукта для своего ios приложения. Но когда добавляю изображения для обложки страницы (обложка это та большая картинка, которая отображается вверху страницы) качество его значительно ухудшается.

Я конечно понимаю, что фейсбук уменьшает размер, но все же какие настройки в фотошопе следует применить, чтобы картинка была с таком качестве как я загружаю?
Перепробовал несколько способов которые описывали в интернете, но мне так и не удалось добиться хорошего результата.

https://www.facebook.com/MakeUpWords  вот страница, сверху обложка.

Comment: 851 × 315 ?

Comment: Простите, а можно по конкретнее. Не понял вопроса.